# Registration Form not saving data in Profile Model, using extended Django User model

Tags: python, django

Recently i am facing a problem in registration. I have made a ** accounts** app in my project for registrations. I don't want to save data in default **User** model in dB. So I have extended **User** model with **OneToOne** relationship with **Profile** model and trying to save the data into "Profile" model but when I submitting the form I don't get any error but data don't save in "Profile" DB.

here is my **models.py** where I make **OneToOne** Relationship with default **"User"** model.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    address=models.CharField(max_length=150)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

I am trying to make **ProfileForm** form and **InfoProfileForm** form here to get the form data in **forms.py**.

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Profile
from django.contrib.auth.forms import ReadOnlyPasswordHashField

class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=20, widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    #form = ProfileForm(data=request.POST, user=request.user)

    class Meta:
        
        model = User
        fields=('username','email','password')

#extra info
class InfoProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('phone','address')
```

Here is my **Views.py** where I am trying to merge two models (default User model and Profile model)

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
# Create your views here.
from .forms import ProfileForm,InfoProfileForm
from django.http.response import HttpResponse

def registration(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
        info_form = InfoProfileForm(request.POST)

        if profile_form.is_valid() and info_form.is_valid():
            user = profile_form.save(commit=True)
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save() 
            profile=info_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user
            profile.phone = user.cleaned_data["phone"]
            profile.address = user.cleaned_data["address"]
            profile.save()

            print('submittef')
        else:
            HttpResponse("<h1>something wrong</h1>")
    else:
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
        info_form = InfoProfileForm(request.POST)
    
    return render(request, 'accounts/registration.html',{'profile_form': profile_form,'info_form': info_form,})
```

here is my HTML template

```
<form action="{% url 'registration' %}" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Register</h1>
    <p>Please fill in this form to create an account.</p>
    <hr>
    <label for="name"><b>Name</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" name="user" required>
    <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" required>
    <label for="phone"><b>Phone</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Phone" name="phone" required>
       <label for="address"><b>Address</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Phone" name="address" required>
    <label for="password"><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password"required>

    <label for="password2"><b>Repeat Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="password2"  required>
    <hr>


    <button type="submit" class="registerbtn">Register</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be try referencing the profile model from the user since it's a one to one field

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
# Create your views here.
from .forms import ProfileForm,InfoProfileForm
from django.http.response import HttpResponse

def registration(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
        info_form = InfoProfileForm(request.POST)

        if profile_form.is_valid() and info_form.is_valid():
            user = profile_form.save(commit=True)
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.profile.phone = user.cleaned_data["phone"]
            user.profile.address = user.cleaned_data["address"]
            user.save()

            print('submitted')
        else:
            HttpResponse("<h1>something wrong</h1>")
    else:
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
        info_form = InfoProfileForm(request.POST)
return render(request, 'accounts/registration.html',{'profile_form':profile_form,'info_form': info_form,})
```

Comment: still, it's not working. Actually I don't want to save any registration data of a user in the default authentication **User** model. but the registration data not saving in profile DB.