# How can i add registration data in another model and can login from that data in django

Tags: python-3.x, django

Recently i am facing a problem in registration. I have made a ** accounts** app in my project for registrations. I don't want to save data in default **User** model in dB. i am trying to make an eCommerce site where people can register to buy products. What is the best way for registrations and log in? Extending the user model could have solved the problem but I want a totally different model for that user who wants to buy products for registration and login. Is it the best way what i am thinking for an eCommerce site registration? How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

I think that is what You need:

1. Make your custom User model where you can add any fields you want (so thats the way for you to make a "totally different model for user who wants to buy products"):

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class MyUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    myField1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    myField2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    myField3 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

2. In settings.py add (myapp - name of your app):

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyUser'
```

3. Make your custom UserCreationForm:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class MyRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = UserCreationForm.Meta.fields + ('myField1', 'myField2', 'myField3')

class MyLoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = UserCreationForm.Meta.fields + ('myField1', 'myField2', 'myField3')
```

4. In views.py add:

```
from . import forms
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

def register_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = forms.MyRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = forms.MyRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': form})

class MyLoginView(auth_views.LoginView):
    redirect_authenticated_user = True
    form_class = forms.MyLogInForm
```

5. In urls.py add:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', views.MyLoginView.as_view(template_name='login.html'), name='login'),
    path('register/', views.register_view, name='register'),
]
```

Comment: i already did this type of work .  can you please tell where i made mistake.            https://stackoverflow.com/q/63567263/14159249